# Fedora 26 dnf update not working behind proxy

Tags: proxy, dnf, fedora-26

On Fedora 26 when I do `sudo dnf update` I get the error

> Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'

I configured both my system-wide proxy and the proxy in dnf.conf. Other connections such as the browser work with this proxy.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this work today? There was a DNS-related outage yesterday; perhaps your working systems simply had the information cached, or were using different DNS servers.

Answer (score 1):

## Login to superuser

```
su
```

## Edit configuration file

```
vi /etc/dnf/dnf.conf
```

## Add your values

```
[main]
gpgcheck=1
installonly_limit=3
clean_requirements_on_remove=True
proxy=http://172.31.1.6:8080
proxy_username=chuttu
proxy_password=verma
```

#### Now update

```
dnf update -y
```

Comment: These values did not work for complete! the ip and user/password any time may be changed!